# How to run method from other class

Tags: java, class, methods

Here's my code:

```
public class Oddmain {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    }

    private static void comp() {
        for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i += 2) {
            System.out.print(i + " ");
        }
    }
}
```

I want it to print out only odd numbers between 1 and 10, which it does fine.  The thing I'm curious about is making it in another class, and calling upon it in the main method.  How would I have the main method call upon something from another class?

I tried using the run method:

```
public void run();
//my for loop here
```

But that didn't really work.  Whenever I move:

```
private static void comp() {
    for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i += 2) {
        System.out.print(i + " ");
    }
}
```

to the other class, it says this:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
The method comp() is undefined for the type Oddmain
    at Oddmain.main(Oddmain.java:4)
```

I think that this means it want me to create the method `comp()` in this class (`Oddmain`), but I want to create in the class `Oddcomp`. This is something I can do, correct?

I'm really new to coding, so please explain stuff very thorough when posting, so I know why I'm doing what I'm doing, and not just copy/pasting.

Comment: How is the compiler supposed to know where and which `comp` method to invoke? What if you had a `comp` method in another class as well?

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Oddmain {
       public static void main(String[] args){

private static void comp() {
  for(int i = 1; i <= 10; i += 2){
    System.out.print(i + " ");
    }
}   
}
```

There is no way this code works fine, you cannot create a new method with in the main statement. I believe you meant:

```
public class Oddmain {
       public static void main(String[] args){
              comp();
       }  

 private static void comp() {
  for(int i = 1; i <= 10; i += 2){
    System.out.print(i + " ");
    }
  }
}
```

To utilise the comp method in another class you can go about this in two ways...

---

NOTE: In both cases you must change the access modifier of your method from private if you wish to use the method in another class.

- Private fields can only be accessed with in the class they are defined in.

1) Create an instance of Oddmain in your other class.

```
public class OtherClass {

    public static void main(String[] args){
        Oddmain s1 = new Oddmain();
        Oddmain.comp();

    }
}
```

2) Call the comp() method in a static manner, static methods are often called by using the class name the static method is defined in, e.g.

```
   Oddmain.comp();
```

Static methods should often be called via the latter format. In both cases you are calling the comp method in Oddmain. Remember static fields belong to a class not an object.

Comment: Your second code need at least one more bracket `}` :)

Answer (score 0):

The problem that you have here it's that you don't close `main` method.

```
public class Oddmain {
    public static void main(String[] args){
    }


    private static void comp() {
       for(int i = 1; i <= 10; i += 2){
           System.out.print(i + " ");
       }
    }   
}
```

And now you can call your method comp from your `main` method:

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    comp();
}
```

I expect it will be helpful for you!